# Issue creating a HMAC-SHA1 hash in Python

Tags: python-3.x, hmac, hmacsha1

I'm having issues generating a signature (in a HMAC-SHA1 hash format), I keep getting a TypeError.

I'm using the following code to generate the signature:

```
from hashlib import sha1
import hmac
import binascii
def getUrl(request):
    devId = 2
    key = '7car2d2b-7527-14e1-8975-06cf1059afe0'
    request = request + ('&' if ('?' in request) else '?')
    raw = request+'devid={0}'.format(devId)
    hashed = hmac.new(key, raw, sha1)
    signature = hashed.hexdigest()
    return 'http://api.domain.com'+raw+'&signature={1}'.format(devId, signature)
print(getUrl('/v2/healthcheck'))
```

The error I keep getting is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\...\Documents\serviceinfo\sig.py", line 12, in <module>
    print(getUrl('/v2/healthcheck'))
  File "C:\Users\...\Documents\serviceinfo\sig.py", line 9, in getUrl
    hashed = hmac.new(key, raw, sha1)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\hmac.py", line 153, in new
    return HMAC(key, msg, digestmod)
  File "C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37-32\lib\hmac.py", line 49, in __init__
    raise TypeError("key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got %r" % type(key).__name__)
TypeError: key: expected bytes or bytearray, but got 'str'
[Finished in 0.1s with exit code 1]
```

Is anyone able to point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your [key value](https://docs.python.org/3/library/hmac.html#hmac.new) must be a byte array of bytes.
to convert a string object to a [bytes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytes) using following code

```
key=bytes(str('7car2d2b-7527-14e1-8975-06cf1059afe0'),'utf8')
```

and then give the key to hamc.new object

**Or**

you can use [bytearray](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#func-bytearray) function instead of bytes

```
key=bytearray(str('7car2d2b-7527-14e1-8975-06cf1059afe0'), 'utf-8')
```

and then give the key to hamc.new object

Comment: Thanks. I've attempted both options and I'm getting a new error: "TypeError: Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing". Any ideas?

Comment: Hi @Matt Have you got your answer?